# wordpress - dropped down menu indicator

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I have decided to learn wordpress during the #COVID19 Lockdown.

In my main menu i have used the dropped down indicator for both parent and child.
After the indicator arrow, there is another “square” undesired character appearing.

[image]

I tried to edit the stlye.css in the child theme as follows,

```
.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children a:after {display: none;}
```

this doesn't fix it.

Any help to correct the problem would be highly appreciated.

```
/*
Theme Name: Avada Child
Description: Child theme for Avada theme
Author: ThemeFusion
Author URI: https://theme-fusion.com
Template: Avada
Version: 1.0.0
Text Domain:  Avada
*/


.fusion-main-menu>ul>li>a{height: auto !important; padding: 25px 0;}
.fusion-header > .fusion-row{display: flex; align-items: center;}
.fusion-main-menu{margin-left: auto;}
.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children a::after,a::before {content: '';} 
.fusion-main-menu .fusion-dropdown-menu .sub-menu li a{line-height: 1.55;}
.fusion-image-wrapper .fusion-rollover{background: rgba(110,50,118,0.9) !important;}
#newsLetterFormDiv{max-width: 500px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;}
#newsLetterFormDiv input[type="email"]{ background: #6d2761; display: block; margin-bottom: 15px; border: solid 1px #ab5d9d; border-radius:5px ; -webkit-border-radius:5px ; -moz-border-radius:5px ; -ms-border-radius:5px ; -o-border-radius:5px ; }
#newsLetterFormDiv input[type="submit"]{ display: inline-block; width: auto; background: #4eb852;  }
#newsLetterFormDiv input[type="submit"]:hover{opacity: 0.65;}
#gallery-1 .gallery-item{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0 10px;}
.fusion-header > .fusion-row{display: flex; align-items: center;}
.fusion-header > .fusion-row > .fusion-main-menu{margin-right: auto; order: 1; margin-left: 0;}
.fusion-header > .fusion-row > .fusion-logo{margin-left: auto; order: 2;}

.tfs-slider .slide-content{ box-sizing: border-box; padding: 25px; background: #6e3276; }
.tfs-slider .slide-content h2.title-heading-center{font-size: 50px !important; line-height: 1.1 !important;}
.tfs-slider .slide-content h3.title-heading-center{font-size: 24px !important;}
.tfs-slider .slide-content-container{ width: auto; left: auto; right: 0; transform:none ; -webkit-transform:none ; -moz-transform:none ; -ms-transform:none ; -o-transform:none ; bottom: 0; padding: 0 !important; top: auto !important; }
#eduPhilosophyBox .flip-box-inner-wrapper{min-height: 350px !important;}
#philoRow .fusion-image-carousel{margin-bottom: 0;}
#philoRow  .fusion-carousel-wrapper{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#ourProgramsRowSection .fusion-title.fusion-title-center{margin-bottom: 0;}
#ourProgramsRow > .fusion-row{max-width: 1020px !important;} 
#recentPostColum .fusion-title{margin-bottom: 0 !important;}
#recentPostColum .fusion-recent-posts{margin-bottom: 0 !important;}
#homeEventListing .fusion-events-post{margin-bottom: 0 !important;}
#homeEventListing .fusion-events-meta h2{font-size: 19px !important; text-transform: none;}


#homeGalList{list-style: none; margin:0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; overflow: hidden; }
#homeGalList > li{width: 50%; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 5px; float: left;}
#homeGalList > li:nth-child(2), #homeGalList > li:nth-child(3){padding: 5px 10px;}
#homeGalList > li >a{position: relative; display: block; overflow: hidden;}
#homeGalList > li >a img{ display: block; width: 100%; transition:all ease 0.2s ; -webkit-transition:all ease 0.2s ; -moz-transition:all ease 0.2s ; -ms-transition:all ease 0.2s ; -o-transition:all ease 0.2s ; }
#homeGalList > li >a h4{background: #6e3276; color: #fff; margin: 0; line-height: 1.1; padding: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
#homeGalList > li >a:hover img{ transform:scale(1.1) ; -webkit-transform:scale(1.1) ; -moz-transform:scale(1.1) ; -ms-transform:scale(1.1) ; -o-transform:scale(1.1) ; }

.hmteaseBlock > .fusion-column-wrapper{opacity: 0; position: relative; z-index: 2;}
.hmteaseBlock:hover > .fusion-column-wrapper{opacity: 1;}
.hmteaseBlock > .fusion-column-inner-bg{ z-index: 1;}
.hmteaseBlock > .fusion-column-inner-bg a > span:before{ content: ""; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); opacity: 0; transition:all ease 0.3s ; -webkit-transition:all ease 0.3s ; -moz-transition:all ease 0.3s ; -ms-transition:all ease 0.3s ; -o-transition:all ease 0.3s ; }
.hmteaseBlock:hover > .fusion-column-inner-bg a > span:before{opacity: 1;}


.fusion-page-title-bar{position: relative;}
.fusion-page-title-bar:after{content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  z-index: 1; }
.fusion-page-title-bar .fusion-page-title-row{position: relative; z-index: 2;}
.founderText{color: #fff;}
.peadalogyLadContentBox .content-container{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 15px; }
#aboutLAcontBox .content-box-column{ margin-top: 90px;}

#menu-program > li{border: 0 !important;}
#menu-program > li > a{box-sizing: border-box; padding:5px 10px; background:#4eb852; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; display: block; }
#menu-program > li > a:before, #menu-program > li > a:after{display: none;}
#menu-program > li > .sub-menu > li:last-child{border: 0 !important;}
```

Comment: I don't have a lot to work with here, but if I would have to make a suggestion. Try to add !important after none, like this:

display: none !important;

Comment: The problem is still there. even after adding !important.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code so that I can see what you have done.
As far as I got you can do this:

```
.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children a::after,a::before {content: '';}
```

Comment: I have added your suggestion and i still don't see that character disappearing. I have copied and pasted the css code.

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting that element using your browser's developer tools. It should show you what styles are being applied to the element and where they are coming from.

In many cases with WordPress there is a plugin which is adding styles after the main stylesheet, therefore overriding them, or adding inline styles via JavaScript.

Comment: I did inspect, it shows as ":: after == $0" that's the one adding that extra character. while in inspect, when i hover over  ":: after == $0", on the web page the following message appears with the unwanted character highlighted,  a.fusion-flex-link.fusion-textcolor-highlight::after.